# jQuery Accordion - set active panel on load depending on previous link

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to set up an accordion so that a different active panel is displayed depending which link is used to open the page.

If you look at the page I'm working on - http://testing.xenongroupadmin.com/lms/admin/index.html - you can see a navigation bar at the top. If you hover on a selection, a drop down box appears.

The first menu item, 'Course Materials' shows three options - 'Workshops', 'Distance Learning' and 'Learning Resources'. Click on any of these links and the target page opens, featuring a jQuery accordion. The titles on this accordion correlate with the three options in the nav bar.

So, to get to the point, what I want is for the appropriate accordion tab to be open depending on which link is clicked. So if I were to click 'Distance Learning' in the navigation menu, the 'materials' page would load with the Distance Learning accordion tab open.

If the 'Course Materials' link is clicked without choosing an option from the sub-menu, all accordion tabs should be closed.

Can anyone help? My server is set up for use with PHP if any server-side scripting is necessary. Also happy to use Ajax if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your sub menu link to materials.html with a hash tag indicating the panel to open. Like 'materials.html#workshop-slides', then use Javascript to parse location.hash on document ready and open the appropriate panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use accordions option ['active'](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active):

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    active : 0
});
```

-1 for closed, 0 for Workshops, 1 for Distance Learning and 2 for Learning Resources

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this in javascript. Pass the active tab reference in the url as #tab-0 (where the number is going to be the index of the tab). Here is a crude implementation to get you started:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a =0;
    if(location.href.indexOf("#tab-1")) a = 1;
    if(location.href.indexOf("#tab-2")) a = 2;
    $('#accordion').accordion({collapsible : true, active : a});  
});
```

If you want to do it from php, then you have to replace the 'none' value with the proper tab index to be opened.

Comment: FYI location.hash gives you just the hash tag.

Comment: Yes, but I use to experience some issues with that in legacy browsers. ;(

Comment: I do recall years ago (I think this was an IE6 issue) that hash in one particular browser would return without the '#'. To correct I just set var hash = location.hash.replace('#', ''); and compared against that.